# Xcode: difference between BACKSPACE + CMD and BACKSPACE?

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I don't understand the difference between using BACKSPACE+CMD and just BACKSPACE.

I see that when I use BACKSPACE+CMD on a element in the Storyboard, that element becomes opaque, and using just BACKSPACE it deletes the element. I can't find the answer in the documentation.

[image]

Comment: When opaque, it means the element has been unistalled for a particular size class. For me, the combination is CMD + delete. Did you check the key binding for your Xcode?

Comment: Uhm, I'm new to storyboards.. you wrote two words I have never read about: "uninstalled" and "size class". I guess I need to start studing storyboards.... I confirm cmd+backspace

Comment: Take a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html

Comment: Thanks. If you write the answer I'll flag it as solution.

Comment: I added my expanded comment as an answer. Thanks. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know, when opaque, it means the component (constraint or UI element) has been unistalled for a particular size class. For me, the combination is Command + Delete.

From [About Designing for Multiple Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) (in bold the key part).

> With size classes, a storyboard or xib file can be used for any
>   available screen area. You build your interface as it will look in
>   most sizes, **then update only the parts that need to change when the
>   available screen size changes**.
>
> A size class identifies a relative amount of display space for the
>   height and for the width. Each dimension can be either compact, for
>   example, the height of an iPhone in landscape orientation, or regular,
>   for example, the height or width of an iPad. Because much of the
>   layout of an app does not need to change for any available screen
>   size, there is an additional value, any.

Hope it helps.

P.S. Did you check the key binding for your Xcode?

Comment: Thanks. I checked key bindings but I don't know how to search that action.